# Можно ли создать @media запрос на sass?

Tags: sass, scss

Здравствуйте. Недавно начал изучать sass, там использую многоуровневые вложения, но немного удобно, когда мне надо сменть элемент в зависимости от размера экрана мне пришлось прописывать такую цепочку в *media* файле:

```
.what-do-we-do>.wr>.content:nth-child(2)>.colum:nth-child(1){
text-align: center;
}
```

можно ли создавать медиа запрос прямо в sass(scss)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конечно можно! Более того, медиа запрос можно вставлять прямо в стили:

```
.what-do-we-do>.wr>.content:nth-child(2)>.colum:nth-child(1){
  text-align: center;
    @media(max-width:1000px){
      text-align: left;
    }
}
```

Также можно их вставить друг в друга, например одна ширина, но разные ориентации.